# print the configuration items getting loaded on server startup

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web.xml, applicationcontext

Can anyone let me now how to enable logging config files getting loaded during startup for tomcat server.

I'd like to print/echo (system.out) the application context beans getting loaded or check the order in which container loads the application context files while starting the server? Or echo the config files getting loaded.

Is there any statement that can be written on xml file itself that can be passed to application or system log files.

Comment: Have you read the [Logging Configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html) from Tomcat's doc?

Comment: Not entirely. Surely I would but I need this logging on eclipse console. Possible? Not on the log4j logger file.

Comment: Yes it is. Just configure your project/tomcat to log to the console, eclipse will handle it just fine.

Comment: You will need a logger of some sort. if you just add system.out on your classes the moment the tomcat loads then it will print it out to what ever is configured, usually the console.

Comment: Well why I asked this question was just to print all the config files getting loaded at server startup and displayed on eclipse's console during server startup.